# Java XML delete Element if age > 30

Tags: java, xml

Hi all :) I have a problem with Java and XML.

I have an XML file with some football players with various age and I want to delete only the Player with age over 30 years.

And this is my Java Source:

```
try {   
         File inputFile = new File("src/players.xml");
         DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);


         System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
         NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("player");
         System.out.println("----------------------------");


         for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {     

               Element eElement = (Element) nNode;


               int ageNumber = Integer.parseInt(eElement.getElementsByTagName("age").item(0).getTextContent());

               if(ageNumber > 30) {
                   temp--;
                   eElement.getParentNode().removeChild(eElement);  
                   doc.normalize();
                   }

               System.out.println("ID : " + eElement
                  .getElementsByTagName("id")
                  .item(0)
                  .getTextContent());

               System.out.println("First Name : " 
                      + eElement
                      .getElementsByTagName("firstName")
                      .item(0)
                      .getTextContent());

               System.out.println("Last Name : " 
               + eElement
                  .getElementsByTagName("lastName")
                  .item(0)
                  .getTextContent());

               System.out.println("Age : " 
               + eElement
                  .getElementsByTagName("age")
                  .item(0)
                  .getTextContent());

            }
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

But the program doesnt delete the element with age > 30.

Anyone could help me please? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "doesnt work" .  what's the problem?  Runtime problem?  Compilation problem?

Comment: The program shows the list the of the player but doesnt delete the older players than 30 years.

Comment: Can you provide a sample XML file?

Answer (score 0):

DOM collections are live so trying to remove elements while iterating over the collection is safely done from the end of the collection. Change `for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {` to `for (int temp = nList.getLength() - 1; temp >= 0 ; temp--) {`.

And of course the document `doc` needs to be serialized back to a file to have the changes persisted, you can use a default `Transformer` or `LSSerializer` for that.